# Override the OpenExeConfiguration method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sdk

How can I use the `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()` in a web ASP project?

I cannot change method used to get the config info, since it's part of a compiled DLL in someone else's SDK. There is no way for me to change it.

Error I'm getting is;

> System.ArgumentException exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe.    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfigurationImpl(ConfigurationFileMap fileMap, Boolean isMachine, ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, String exePath, Boolean preLoad)
> at system.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel)

I tried solving it by adding the following line;

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @"\\PathTo\Web.config");
```

But it does not solve the issue.

My next bet is to somehow override the `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()` method so when it's called, it should instead call the `ConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration()` which is the web version of the same method.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I understand: the call to `OpenExeConfiguration` is in the compiled .dll and you need to override it so that it behaves differently?

You can't. It seems odd that someone would compile a library that can only function in a non-web environment unless they had ruled out the possibility of using it any other way.

It's a long shot, but you could try decompiling it with [JetBrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). It can export a new Visual Studio project which you can edit and recompile. I've had to do that on occasions when I either didn't have source code or wasn't sure it was the right source code.

In the process of decompiling and looking through it maybe you'll even find another way to load configuration settings.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHannen for your explanative answer.
I actually already tried this exact software and solution, but I ran in to five more issues, so I wanted to double-check if this is indeed my only possible route. With enough time and patience I'll menage, but let's see if somebody comes up with anything else. Otherwise you well deserve it!